# JBoss AS 7 migration - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator

Tags: hibernate, jboss, seam, jboss7.x

I have an application running on JBoss AS 4.2.3 and am trying to migrate this to JBoss AS 7.0.2.  I am also upgrading seam from 2.1.1 to 2.2.2.  I have resolved a few of the class not found exceptions, but I am stuck on

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator`

My full stack trace is below.

I'm not very clear on the new class loader in AS 7.  Does Hibernate 4 work with seam 2.2.2? I have tried specifying the exports in jboss-deployment-structure.xml to use org.hibernate and org.hibernate.validator.  However, when I look in the jars in these locations, I do not see the ClassValidator class...

I have also tried adding hibernate 3 jars to the EAR/lib and specifying them in the manifest, but that does not change anything. I see that hibernate 3 hibernate-validator.jar does contain the classValidator class, but it still doesn't find it.

UPDATE I also tried hibernate-validator-legacy-4.0.2.GA.jar

```
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar
hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar
hibernate-validator-3.1.0.GA.jar
```

```
14:16:07,776 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.Component] (MSC service thread 1-2) Component: Test, scope: EVENT, type: JAVA_BEAN, class: com.test.Test 
14:16:07,789 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/oneSourceUI]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create Component: Test
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1202) [jboss-seam.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.installComponents(Initialization.java:1118) [jboss-seam.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:737) [jboss-seam.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36) [jboss-seam.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [:1.7.0_01]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [:1.7.0_01]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0_01]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/ClassValidator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_01]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442) [:1.7.0_01]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808) [:1.7.0_01]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.initMembers(Component.java:553) [jboss-seam.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.(Component.java:247) [jboss-seam.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.(Component.java:208) [jboss-seam.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1186) [jboss-seam.jar:]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator from [Module "deployment.test-ear.ear.jboss-seam.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
    ... 18 more

14:16:07,798 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Mojarra (1.2_15-20110809-SNAPSHOT) for context '/test
14:16:07,828 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSF1051: Service entry 'org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfInjectionProvider' does not extend DiscoverableInjectionProvider.  Entry will be ignored.
14:16:07,829 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
14:16:07,852 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
14:16:07,854 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/test] startup failed due to previous errors
14:16:07,855 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) registering web context: /oneSourceUI
14:16:08,101 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/oneSourceUI] has not been started
14:16:08,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment of "test-ear.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"test-ear.ear/test-ejb.jar#testBackout\" missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.testBackoutDatasource ]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"test-ear.ear/test-ejb.jar#test\" missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.testDatasource ]"]}
14:16:08,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Stopped deployment test-ejb.jar in 760ms
14:16:08,857 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Stopped deployment jboss-seam.jar in 761ms
14:16:09,613 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Stopped deployment oneSourceUI.war in 1517ms
14:16:09,720 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Stopped deployment oneSourceUI-ear.ear in 1624ms
14:16:09,728 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"test-ear.ear/test-ejb.jar#testBackout\" missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.testBackoutDatasource ]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"test-ear.ear/test-ejb.jar#test\" missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.testDatasource ]"]}}}
```

Comment: Please ignore the paths and names in the stack trace as I changed most of them to post here.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Incompatible Java EE application servers... (even if they're from the same vendor).

Comment: Strange, I just got it to work with Hibernate 4 and having hibernate-validator 3.1.0.GA in the deployment (no Hibernate 3 JARs) to satisfy Seam 2's hard dependency on hibernate-validator. At least this works for my test HTTP servlet. BTW I found JBoss AS 7.0.1 to be the stablest.

Answer (score 5):

Classloading model changed in JBoss 7. It hides much stuff that's not explicitly declared.

You have to get familar with these links:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-HowtoresolveClassNotFoundExceptionsandNoCLassDefFoundErrors

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Answer (score 3):

1 - I solve this problem by declare module in jboss7.1.1 
2 - modify MANIFEST.MF file in lib folder

in \jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\ folder create this folders :

\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules**org\hibernate\validator\main**

then I copy file hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar into the folder of main\

then I create file module.xml in main folder and modify that by bellow code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate.validator">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.common-core"/>
    <module name="org.joda.time"/>
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    <module name="org.apache.xerces" services="import"/>
    <module name="sun.jdk" services="import"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Now, your module created in jboss modules.

look at this line :

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate.validator">
```

you must use org.hibernate.validator in Dependencies part in your MANIFEST.MF file like bellow :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: Sahand Samaneh
Implementation-Title: Sahand System Security Product
Implementation-Version: 5.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.sahand.product
Built-By: pooladi.morteza
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_21
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.4
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Dependencies: com.sahand.common.util,com.sahand.common.security,com.sahand.model.common,com.sahand.model.user.management,com.sahand.model.security,com.sahand.security.api,com.sahand.security.persistence,com.sahand.security.service,org.apache.commons.codec,org.slf4j,ch.qos.logback.core,ch.qos.logback.classic,javax.validation.api,org.hibernate.validator
```

then your problem must be pass :D

if you get any message of ClassNotFoundException , you must declare jboss module and use name of that in your MANIFEST.MF file .

:D

Answer (score -1):

putting this in persistence.xml worked for me on this error:

```
property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"
```